# Inserting Pivot table using VBA working in Excel 2013 but not in Excel 2010 , NO changes to code made

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of code to insert a pivot table which works fine when i run it on excel 2013 but when i try the same in excel 2010 , it throws an error stating
"Invalid Procedure Call" , i am stumped , not sure how to proceed.
Here is the code.

```
Sub piviot()
Workbooks("TimeSheet_Aggregator.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Splice-M").Activate

 Set Data_sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Splice-M")
  Set Pivot_sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot")
  PivotName = "PivotTable1"
Call PickedActualUsedRange
  Set StartPoint = Data_sht.Range("A1")
  Set DataRange = Selection

  'DataRange.Interior.Color = vbGreen

  NewRange = Data_sht.Name & "!" & _
    DataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
  If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(DataRange.Rows(1)) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "One of your data columns has a blank heading." & vbNewLine _
      & "Please fix and re-run!.", vbCritical, "Column Heading Missing!"
    Exit Sub
  End If
Sheets("Pivot").Activate
Cells(1, 1).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        NewRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=Worksheets("Pivot").`enter code here`Range("A1") _
, TableName:=PivotName, DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion15**
```

Comment: Here's your problem:  `'DataRange.Interior.Color = vbGreen `  Clearly it should be:  `'DataRange.Interior.Color = vbBlue & vbGold `   O.o  Sorry, I'm actually not sure - have you tried stepping through the code via debugger to nail down which line is failing on ?  That would help drastically in troubleshooting.

Comment: lol.. Yeah its actually in this part  ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        NewRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=Worksheets("Pivot").`enter code here`Range("A1") _
, TableName:=PivotName, DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion15**

Comment: When i step into the above piece , its throwing the error"Invalid Procdedure call"  . IT was working yesterday when i used excel 2013 on which this macro was originally written , now i need to continue using Excel 2010 and this bugger pops up..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok .. i figured it out..Hope this helps to others with similar issue.

I recorded a macro using Excel 2010 and saw that in

`ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        NewRange, Version:=**xlPivotTableVersion15**).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=Worksheets("Pivot").Range("A1") _
, TableName:=PivotName, DefaultVersion _
        :=**xlPivotTableVersion15**`

**for 2013 its xlPivotTableVersion15 and for 2010 its xlPivotTableVersion14,**

S simply replacing did it for me :-)